# EF 6 Code-First "Update-Database"-issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently having an issue with the "update-database" command that I run in the console to update my database based on the entities I create.

I've developed a basic CMS that I've moved into a new project, but when trying to "upload" the database using the "update-database" command it comes up with the following error:

```
Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

This error seems to happen no matter what sort of EF command I type in. E.g. I tried enabling migrations, and I get the same error.

NOTE:
This works in the original project with the CMS, but after copying it DIRECTLY over (no changes whatsoever) I get the error.

Thank you in advance.